# Python: Match a special caracter with regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x, matching

Hi everyone I'm using the re.match function to extract pieces of string within a row from the file.

My code is as follows:

```
## fp_tmp => pointer of file

for x in fp_tmp:
        try:
            cpuOverall=re.match(r"(Overall CPU load average)\s+(\S+)(%)",x)
            cpuUsed=re.match(r"(Total)\s+(\d+)(%)",x)
            ramUsed=re.match(r"(RAM Utilization)\s+(\d+\%)",x)

            ####Not Work####
            if cpuUsed is not None: cpuused_new=cpuUsed.group(2)
            if ramUsed is not None: ramused_new=ramUsed.group(2)
            if cpuOverall is not None: cpuoverall_new=cpuOverall.group(2)
        except:
            searchbox_result = None
```

Each field is extracted from the following corresponding line:

```
ramUsed => RAM Utilization 2%
cpuUsed => Total 4%
cpuOverall => Overall CPU load average 12%
```

ramUsed, cpuUsed, cpuOverall are the variable where I want write the result!!
Corretly line are:

```
(space undefined) RAM Utilization 2%
(space undefined) Total 4%
(space undefined) Overall CPU load average 12%
```

When I execute the script all variable return a value: None.
With other variable the script work corretly.

Why the code not work in this case? I use the python3

I think that the problem is a caracter % that not read.

Do you have any suggestions?

**PROBLEM 2:**

```
## fp_tmp => pointer of file

for x in fp_tmp:
        try:
            emailReceived=re.match(r".*(Messages Received)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)",x)

            ####Not Work####
            if emailReceived is not None: emailreceived_new=emailReceived.group(2)

        except:
            searchbox_result = None
```

Each field is extracted from the following corresponding on 2 lines in a file:

```
[....]
Counters:                               Reset          Uptime        Lifetime
  Receiving
    Messages Received                   3,406           1,558           3,406
[....]
Rates (Events Per Hour):             1-Minute       5-Minutes      15-Minutes
  Receiving
    Messages Received                       0               0               0
    Recipients Received                     0               0               0
[....]
```

I want extract only second occured, that:

```
Rates (Events Per Hour):             1-Minute       5-Minutes      15-Minutes
  Receiving
    Messages Received                       0               0               0 <-this
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you just show the input and expected match you want?

Answer (score 0):

`cpuOverall` line: you forgot that there is more information at the start of the line. Change to

```
'.*(Overall CPU load average)\s+(\S+%)'
```

`cpuUsed` line: you forgot that there is more information at the start of the line. Change to

```
'.*(Total)\s+(\d+%)'
```

`ramUsed` line: you forgot that there is more information at the start of the line... Change to

```
'.*(RAM Utilization)\s+(\d+%)'
```

Remember that [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) looks for an exact match *from the start*:

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning** of `string` match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. [..]

With these changes, your three variables are set to the percentages:

```
>>> print (cpuused_new,ramused_new,cpuoverall_new)
4% 2% 12%
```

Comment: Excuse me, the corretly line are with the % post a number.
ramUsed, cpuUsed and cpuOverall are the variable where I want write a result of this line:
RAM Utilization 2%
Total 4%
Overall CPU load average 12%

Comment: Hi, when I want print a variable I read this error:

print(cpuoverall_new)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cpuoverall_new' referenced before assignment

Comment: @SavioZ: that's an unrelated problem. You only *create* `cpuoverall_new` if you find a match but always try to print it. Create your variables at the top and this problem goes away. Did my answer get the correct output? It did on my side.

Comment: Thanks a lot...now it's work :)...Can you help me with Problem 2 on my post ?? Thanks a lot!